How to read mixed Text/BLOB data from a column using SQLite.swift
Using SQLite.swift, I try to read data from a table column where some rows have been added as text strings and some as binary (BLOB) data, e.g. as X'414243'.
Now, when I try to read a Row, it might contain either a String or a Data object, it appears. I am currently reading the data as follows:
static let nameString = Expression<String?>("name")
static let nameData = Expression<Data?>("name")

let name: String

init(conn: Connection, row: Row) {
    if let name = row[MyClass.nameString] {
        self.name = name
    } else {
        if let name = row[MyClass.nameData] {
            self.name = String(data: name, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? ""
        } else {
            self.name = ""
        }
    }

Is that the way I'm supposed to do this, or is there a better way?
And since I have other tables and columns with the same "issue", I wonder how I can make this easier for all cases where I have textual data sometimes stored as blobs like above.
I'd like to avoid having to create two Expression<…> types each time where I read one of these mixed-content columns. Can this be done more smartly?
